# Filter of aggregate function not working in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield, qgis-expression

I use an aggregate function with a filter like this

```
aggregate(
    ...,
    filter:="observatoire_uuid" = '{54ab58ff-aefc-495d-88af-83ded1742df3}'
    )
```

the result is ok.
But if I change `'{54ab58ff-aefc-495d-88af-83ded1742df3}'` by the result of this function:

```
aggregate(
    'observatoire_626e5cbe_01f8_4abf_a445_98e78c6b4dae',
    'min',
    "uuid",
    distance(
        $geometry,
        geometry(
            @parent
        )
    ) < 50
)
```

the filter doesn't work, and I am sure that the result of the above expression is: `'{54ab58ff-aefc-495d-88af-83ded1742df3}'`

Answer (score 0):

### The solution (principle)

Inside a filter, you can't include further complex expressions. So you have to stick the expression togeteher using [`eval()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#eval) function to first create the value of your 2nd expression and then stick the output of this together with a string to create a text string representing the final expression. Then use `eval()` to actually "run" the expression.

It works like this pattern (see at the bottom of this solution for a more detailed explanation):

```
eval ('my string 1' || my expression || 'my string 2')
```

### Step by step

1. Create your desired output with the second expression you provided: lines 5 to 13 in my expression.
2. Stick this together with a string (strings work inside single quotes: `'`) that provide the code from your first expression - in my case lines 2 to 4 and 2nd last line. Connect the three elements with pipes: `||`. Be aware how to use quotes (see at the bottom for details)!
3. Inclose everything in an `eval()` function: it converts the text (string) sticked together in step 2 to an expression that is evaluated and outputs the desired result:

```
eval (
    'aggregate(
        ...,  -- everything here that is normally in single quotes ' must be in two single quotes: ''
        filter:="observatoire_uuid" = '  || 
        aggregate(
            'observatoire_626e5cbe_01f8_4abf_a445_98e78c6b4dae',
            'min', 
            "uuid", 
            distance(
                $geometry,
                geometry(@parent)
            ) < 50
        ) || 
    ')'
)
```

### Be aware of

Make sure to get all quotes correctly, otherwise it will not work:

- single qutotes: `'`
- two repeated single quotes `''`: everywhere where in your expression you have the three points `...` as placeholders (line 3 above), you should double single quotes by another single quote to mask it.
- double quotes `"`

### Explanation of the pattern shown above

Inside `eval()` you stick together two strings with an expression. The expression is your 2nd expresion, strings 1 and 2 are your 1st expression, split up after the equal sign `=`. So you have `aggregate ( ... =` (first part of your 1st string) enclosed in single quotes to make it a string. Everything inside this string that initially has single quotes must be written with two single quotes. The second element sticked together is the output of the epxreesion: `'{54ab58ff-aefc-495d-88af-83ded1742df3}'`. At the end, add a closing bracket `')'`, again as a string (`my string 2`).